# FutureBuilder in DART : "The method 'data' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the call..."

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

It's been a few days now that I'm working on a flutter code by following tutorials to learn how to use Firebase with it. Nevertheless I completely block on a step that the person manages to realize, I have however copied the code at 100% and here is the error that I have:

`The method 'data' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').`

Here is the code:

```
class GetUserData extends StatelessWidget {
  final String documentId;
  final String fieldName;
  final String fieldTitle;

  GetUserData(
      {super.key,
      required this.documentId,
      required this.fieldName,
      required this.fieldTitle});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = firestore.collection('Users');
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(data[fieldName]),
            subtitle: Text(data[fieldTitle]),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

I've tried many things:

`Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data();`

`return FutureBuilder( future: users.doc(documentId).get(), builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) { Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>; return ListTile( title: Text(data[fieldName]), subtitle: Text(data[fieldTitle]), ); });`

Here I don't have the error but a crash when I debug with `_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)`

I have looked everywhere and I don't understand how to solve this,

Thank you so much for your help,

Comment: just add if(snapshot.hasData) and the error will be fixed .

Comment: or copy the answer of @pmatatias and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not decoding the response from the firebase properly, try considering the below code:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(documentId) 
            .get(),
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error = ${snapshot.error}');
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text("Loading");
          }
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data()!;
          return Text(data['fieldName']); // give your valid data here
        },
      )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: That's right! Thanks a lot, thanks to you I was able to understand that I had coded wrong for my MAP reading. 
'            title: Text(data[fieldName]),
            subtitle: Text(data[fieldTitle]),'
Indeed in the title I was displaying the value linked to the corresponding key, but in the subtitle I couldn't display the key by the value ! I just had to put the name of the key. Thank you both, finally I can see the end!

Answer (score 0):

try to handle all condition

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = firestore.collection('Users');
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
           /// success fetch data
          if(snapshot.hasData){
           Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(snapshot.data);
           return ListTile(
            title: Text(data[fieldName]),
            subtitle: Text(data[fieldTitle]),
          );
          }
         /// failed and throw error
          else if(snapshot.hasError){
            return Text('${snapshot.error}');
          } 
        /// loading condition
        else {
        return Center(child:CircularProggressIndicator());
         }
        });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it is true that I had not put the conditions. I still have the same problem with the error:
"A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Map<String, dynamic>'."
"The method 'data' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')."

Comment: Api response is json String, you may need to `decode`  it